# crontab -l output to file

Tags: bash, shell, crontab

I want to be able to output my current crontab to a file, in order to check and append it automatically.

```
crontab -l > somefile
```

creates an empty file.  There must be a simple way of doing this, right?

Comment: That command works for me, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct way, could it be that you have empty crontab? :)

Comment: Gah, you're right!  I thought that when I ran the command that the message crontab usually returns (stating no crontab for <user>) would appear.

Comment: For that to happen you'd need to redirect standard error too.

Comment: (But you probably don't want it, I see no reason why would you)